# TCPDump, can't understand these parts

Tags: tcp, tcpdump, syntax

I need help to understand the bold part of this line :

```
01:04:28.539138 IP 90.2.255.58.37727 > 71.197.145.153.46872: . 9801:11201(1400) ack 0 win 2003
```

**9801:11201(1400)**

9801 seems to be the data sequence numbers, am I right ?
But what is **11201** and **(1400)** ?

I often see **x:y(z)** where **x = y** and **z = 0**.

Can someone explain me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 9801 = TCP starting sequence
- 11201 = TCP ending sequence
- (1400) =
  difference between 9801 and 11201 = data carried in packet